# Full Screen Window Background

Tags: android

I'm looking for the window background img to completely fill the screen but I also want the content to sit between the status bar and nav bar (not behind them).

Attempt 1: results in the window background drawable sitting between the status and nav bars, not behind them

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/loggedout_bg</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/logged_out_system_bar_color</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/logged_out_system_bar_color</item>
```

Attmpt 2: results in the drawable filling the screen but the content going behind the status/nav bars

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/loggedout_bg</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

I've tried both with and without `fitsSystemWindows` in the main activity parent layout (constraintLayout).

So... How do I have a full screen background image AND have the in-app content sit between the system bars?

Answer (score 0):

override the window manager layout params and set your margintop to the height of the status bar and margin bottom. it will be in between navbar and statusbar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not looking for the image to be between the status bar and nav bar, I'm looking for it to be full height of the device with the app content (buttons and whatnot) being in between the status bar a nav bar